# "Oops something went wrong :( try again later " in WebClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          string url = "https://example.tj/service";

          using (var webClient = new WebClient())
          {
                String str = "SomeTextForText";
                var response = webClient.UploadString(url, str);
          }
    }
}
```

Why I am getting

> Oops something went wrong :( try again later

on the line

```
webClient.UploadString(url, str);
```

Comment: Because the server said so? It’s not from this code.

Comment: This is not MVC code.  This is webforms.

Comment: Like @SamiKuhmonen said, this is a server response message.

Comment: Is it error or everything ok?
if this is error, how to solve it?